# How to solve ExpIntegralEi?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am solving an integral in Mathematica but there is a function `ExpIntegralEi` appearing in the answer which I am unsure what it means and how to solve it. I have read the Wolfram documentation but I don't know what it means in my case. Kindly guide me how to solve it.

```
w = Integrate[((2*x^2)/(2*a - x))*Exp[(-(1/2))*x*y], x]
```

The answer given by Mathematica is:

```
2*(-((2*(2 + 2*a*y + x*y))/(E^((x*y)/2)*y^2)) +
   (4*a^2*ExpIntegralEi[a*y - (x*y)/2])/E^(a*y))
```

Comment: It is just a special function much like `Sin`, `BesselJ`, or `LegendreP` to name a few.  Mathematica did a pretty good job in this case.  What further solving are you interested in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`ExpIntegralEi`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpIntegralEi.html) is no different from any other function.

```
w[a_, x_, y_] = Integrate[((2*x^2)/(2*a - x))*Exp[(-(1/2))*x*y], x]

(* -2 (-((2 E^(-((x y)/2)) (2 + 2 a y + x y))/y^2) + 
   4 a^2 E^(-a y) ExpIntegralEi[a y - (x y)/2]) *)
```

Plotting,

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Evaluate@w[a, x, y],
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  ClippingStyle -> None,
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@
     {x, y, w})],
 {{a, 3}, 0, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]